# Suggest some good Lightbox jquery which supports .avi file

Tags: jquery, lightbox, avi

Can any one suggest me a lightbox jquery which supports .avi file??

Comment: I think a lightbox is the least of your problems....

Comment: Those "suggest me" kind of questions usually get closed really fast... <5 min

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [lightbox](http://www.htmlstack.com/lighterbox/#close)

And add this to play avi.

```
  <object data="data/test.avi" type="video/x-msvideo" width="320" height="255">
  <param name="src" value="data/test.avi">
  <param name="autoStart" value="0">
  alt : <a href="data/test.avi">test.avi</a>
  </object>
```

Works on all Browsers. Chrome not tested.